# Cassandra Rack awareness

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I am new to Cassandra and trying to setup a Cassandra 2.0 cluster using 4 nodes, 2 each in 2 different racks. All are in same data centre. This is what I see in the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html):

> To use racks correctly:
>
> - Use the same number of nodes in each rack.
> - Use one rack and place the
>     nodes in different racks in an alternating pattern. This allows you
>     to still get the benefits of Cassandra's rack feature, and allows for
>     quick and fully functional expansions. Once the cluster is stable,
>     you can swap nodes and make the appropriate moves to ensure that
>     nodes are placed in the ring in an alternating fashion with respect
>     to the racks.

What I have understood is, in `cassandra-rackdc.properties`, I need to use single rack name even though I have 2 racks and then place the nodes in such an order that they are placed in an alternating fashion - `RAC1-NODE1`, `RAC2-NODE1`, `RAC1-NODE2`, `RAC2-NODE2`.

Just wanted to know if this is correct. If yes, how do I enforce this order while adding nodes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This writing seems to me a little unclear, but this may be due to me not being a native English speaker. The first statement though is clear - you should definitely have an equal amount of nodes in each rack. Regarding the second statement - that is where I am uncertain what it means. I suspect that this piece of the [documentation](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html) was carried from a long time ago, and needs some revisiting. My understanding is that if you use [PropertyFileSnitch](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureSnitchPFSnitch_t.html), then you should use appropriate rack names for your nodes, you just need to place them in an alternating order into the ring. Ordering is done via an explicit [token assignment](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configGenTokens_c.html), or, if you use [virtual nodes](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeDistribute_c.html) in the datacenter, then it is done automatically for you.

Comment: Hi Roman,
Thanks a lot for replying to my post. I was referring to the latest Cassandra Documentation: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html?scroll=archPlanAntiPattern__AntiPatRack

I am using GossipingPropertyFileSnitch. I have read that the nodes from 2 racks need to be added in an alternating fashion, or the first node from the rack will become a hotspot. But not sure how to maintain the order of nodes since I am not assigning the tokens. I am using vnodes.

Comment: As I said in my answer - if you use vnodes, then you should not worry - just make sure that the ring knows which rack each node is in.

Answer (score 0):

The rack related information applies only to the single-token architecture and not applicable to virtual nodes. In case you are using vNodes then you need not worry about it.